# Sum of weighted normal distributions, how to solve $P(X<x) = y$ for $x$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, error-function

How do I solve the following equation for $x$

$$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}\frac{1}{2}\left((f-1)\cdot\erf\left(\dfrac{c-x}{\sqrt2\,b}\right)-f\erf\left(\dfrac{r-x}{\sqrt2\,d}\right)\right)=y$$

I need this to solve this problem :

I have a distribution, built by the sum of two normal distributions, one multiplied by $(1-f)$ and the other multiplied by $f$. The sum of both is multiplied by $g$. like this (where $0 \leq f < 1$) :

$$\left(\frac{(1-f) e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x-c}{b}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } b}+\frac{f e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x-r}{d}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2
\pi } d}\right)
$$

I need to know the $x$ where $P(X < x) = y$.

First equation is the cumulative distribution or I did a mistake somewhere?

Comment: A bit late at the party but... anyone believing that the barycenter of PDFs the OP is interested in is the PDF of the barycenter of independent random variables considered in the accepted answer, when $f\ne0,1$, should start by checking variances, say (the means being about the only coinciding characteristics of these two objects...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do this analytically then you need a convolution.  I would not.

If your two normal distributions $X_1\sim \mathcal N(a,b^2)$ and $X_2\sim \mathcal N(c,d^2)$ are independent then an easier approach is to say $fX_1\sim \mathcal N\left(fa,f^2 b^2\right)$ and $(1-f)X_2\sim \mathcal N\left((1-f)c,(1-f)^2d^2\right)$ so $$X=fX_1+(1-f)X_2 \sim \mathcal N\left(fa+(1-f)c,f^2 b^2+(1-f)^2d^2\right)$$ and given the mean and variance of $X$ you can solve $P(X\le x)=y$ in the usual way for a normal distribution.

Comment: No. A barycenter of PDFs is not the PDF of some barycenter of independent random variables.